# ANGULAR: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, angular, express, deployment, cors

I was able to pass this error with some local temporary fixes. But now, I'm moving the application to web. Trying to figure out this CORS error for two days. On my VDS I have x.x.x.x:4200 and x.x.x.x:3000 as angular and nodejs/express setup. Both can be accessible on internet.

What I have tried:

- Set CORS related headers on both client and server.
- Set `app.use(cors());`

Maybe my tries were wrong so you can suggest same ways with some clarifications.

[image]

Get request on client side:

```
apiUrl = 'http://46.245.165.120:3000/';
this.http.get(this.apiUrl + `users/${type}`, { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` ,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
        }});
```

Server side headers and CORS setup:

```
var originsWhitelist = [
    'http://localhost:4200',      //this is my front-end url for development
    'http://x.x.x.x:4200',
    'http://www.myproductionurl.com'
];
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        var isWhitelisted = originsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, isWhitelisted);
    },
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {

    var origin = req.headers.origin;

    if (originsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST'); // added OPTIONS as an allowed method
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,x-access-token');
    res.header('access-control-allow-credentials', true);

    return next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain)
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant server code as text, not images.

Comment: @jfriend00 there it is

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-* in HTTP-Request should not be required. Could you live with `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` or making origin configurable by stage (dev vs. prod) and set explicitly one origin?

Comment: @DavidRenner I didn't understand. I can't even live that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made requests to my rest api from [here](https://robwu.nl/cors-anywhere.html), requests was able to return 200 respond so I realized the problem was on my angular application. All of my problem was being the apiUrl a localhost. I was making the requests to `localhost:3000` not `x.x.x.x:3000`. A little oversight but a huge timewaste so I wanted to answer own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code on your backend side (node / express) :

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors({
  origin: [
    'http://localhost:4200',         //this is my front-end url for development
    'http://x.x.x.x:4200',
    'http://www.myproductionurl.com'
  ]
}))

app.get('/my-api-endpoint', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({message: 'This API endpoint is CORS enabled.'})
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
})
```

and on your frontend side (Angular) :

```js
this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/users/${type}`, { 
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`
  }
);
```

more details on [how to use CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) with `node` and `express`.

Comment: I realised the problem is completely different.